Increasing the weight capacity of a meek table
I understand this question as probably been asked to death by now, but I am quiet naïve in these matters so I am hoping for a pretty black and white answer.
I am currently looking at this Ikea table. 
The dimensions being as follows:
Max. load: 15 kg
Max. load/shelf: 5 kg
Free height under furniture: 7 cm
Height: 52 cm
Length: 80 cm
Width: 31 cm

I want to use it as a stand for something that has a weight of 25kgs, which is 10 kgs more than the max load, the reason for this particular table is the dimensions and it is cheap.
So the question I have is if I was to get hold of some angle brackets, say something
like:

and bolt those brackets into the inside corners of the top and bottom would that increase supported weight? At all? Or would that not really achieve anything?

Hi, welcome to Woodworking! "I understand this question as probably been asked to death by now" As an SE member of long standing if it had you should know, not be guessing, as you'll have done the required diligent research prior to asking the Q.... We have had a number of similar queries over the years (and other Qs about increasing load capacity in stuff of dissimilar construction).

This question is difficult to answer for several reasons. IF the weight is a single item at the middle of the span then the shelf material may sag and the brackets at the corners will offer less support. You also mention bolting ( I assume you mean screwing) the angles.  The shelf panels are thin, lower density and the screws may not hold well.

I would be very careful - some Ikea furniture is actually made of melamine covered CARDBOARD sandwich (!) - you can usually tell by surprisingly low weight - and if that would be construction material used for this table (and max. load would suggest that it might), there is almost no easy way to strengthen it.

I recommend that you keep shopping and find a table that is designed to support your required weight.
The boards used in the table are made to a thickness and of a material type that have been given a rating of 15 kg. Angle brackets alone won't change that.
With some creativity and experimentation and a little skill you can get the table to support the weight you want by adding wood and strengthening joints. Going this far will change the look of the table and require some kind of finish on the added wood that will match or blend in with the original table.

Thanks for your answer. I did end up find something that works even better in a complete different subsection at Ikea, it is weird that a shoe stand has better support than a book table...and I mean significantly more support...for shoes. But hey it does the job. As for the answer, thank you, I wasn't sure if angle brackets would actually add the support in general so you have cleared that up for me.
